# How should I update an NSTableView from another class (that gets triggered from that view)?

Tags: objective-c, notifications, nsurlconnection, nstableview

I have a class I'm using to download large files using NSURLConnection. I have another class which is my NSTableView.

What's the best way to go about updating the NSTableView to show download speed and progress? Should I use notifications and pass the speed & percentage when a download has started? How would I go about getting the cell? Would I have to iterate through my whole tableView looking for a match (on title or something) each time?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by passing my NSTableCellView in a dictionary (with other information regarding what was displayed) to my class.